# Hyper.js 3.0.2 terminal tab titles not working

Tags: terminal

I have `hyper.js` 3.0.2 terminal on mac (`10.14.3`). 
My goal is to change the tab title like `https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyperterm-title`.

But it not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please begin following what is written in [the "Usage" section of their GitHub's Readme](https://github.com/parro-it/hyperterm-title#usage):

> To test this out, you can tell the shell to suggest a different title:
>
> ```
> function title() { echo -e "\033]0;${1:?please specify a title}\007" ; }
>
> title "My Title"
> ```

And then, to persist this function, add it to end of your shell profile file (.bash_profile in case of Bash, .zprofile in case of ZSH).

Comment: The link to hyperterm-title says that it has been deprecated and that it no longer works for hyperterm version > 1.0